can power automate save an excel output as unicode
I have returned an excel table from office script into power automate. However when i save the file as a txt file. Notepad++ detect the file as UTF-8
Is it possible to replicate  Excel's "Save As Unicode" in Power Automate,
so that when i open the file in notepad++ it  detects the BOM and interprets the file as UTF-16 LE
notepad++ file detection
i tried to put decodeUriComponent('%FF%FE') in front of the content(compose output) but it still returning a utf-8 file.
Also tried to concat using concat(decodeUriComponent('%FF%FE'),outputs('Compose')) but still returns a utf-8 .
power automate flow

I am not familiar with any way to change the encoding of a file in power automate. However, if you want to use the UTF-16 LE encoding, you must convert it before handing it over to power automate. Depending on what action you are using to retrieve the file content, there is a parameter that infers the content of a file. This should be set to no if you do not want it to change to UTF-8
